# JQuery - Load HTML file and get script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu with say 5 buttons. On each item click, I want to AJAX load a HTML file that contains some script. The loaded file looks like the following:

```
<div>
  someContent...
</div>
<script>
FileScriptObject = {
  init: function() {
  },

  cleanup: function() {
  },
};
</script>
```

I want to be able to $("#someDiv").load("externalFile.html"); and somehow, get hold of that FileScriptObject. Is it possible?

Comment: Hm, I have a potential answer for myself. I can add some script at the bottom of that loaded HTML that passed the FileScriptObject to a known registered object, that can then handle calling it. Such as window.SomeManager.executeMe(FileScriptObject);

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery function for that:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

Comment: This doesn't tell me how I can get hold of the script object contained in the loaded HTML file.

Comment: Why do you want to get hold of it? Are they parsed out by jQuery?

Comment: When I was out these layers when selecting different menu items, I want to be able to call a "Cleanup" method on the old layer, and an "Init" when the new layer has finished loading. I think I solved it though, see my comment on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then I think you are interested in loading a new script file dynamically. This is entirely possible; for example if I wanted to load a js file called `newScript.js` then I can create a script tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="newScript.js"></script>` and add it to the header. To do this I can do the following:

```
var head = document.getElementByTagName("head")[0];
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.type = "text/javascript";
newScript.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readystate == "complete") {
        // Script loaded
    }
}
newScript.src = "newScript.js";
newScript.onload = function() {
    // Script loaded
}
head.appendChild(newScript);
```

Note that there are two different load handlers, this is because the `readystate` check is for IE and `onload` is for others.